# Undestanding Custom Component and V-Model in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**NOTE:** I have made a video version of this quesiton, which you can view here:
https://www.loom.com/share/6a23d0791c2444068e964b388ed5497e

---

The VueJS documentation dicusses how to use `v-model` with `components`:  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

If I create a component exactly has written in the documentation, it works just fine.  Here is the code:

```
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  props: ['value'],
  template: `
    <input
      v-bind:value="value"
      v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    >
  `
})
```

But now let me try and change the name of the prop in that component -- for example, to `bar`:

```
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  props: ['bar'],
  template: `
    <input
      v-bind:value="bar"
      v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    >
  `
})
```

Now it only half-works.  That is to say, let's say I am binding `custom-input` to a data property called `message`, like this: `<custom-input v-model="message"></custom-input>`.  If I dynamically update the value of `message`, then the value of `custom-input` will update -- **but only once**. If I update the value again it will not update the value of `custom-input`.

However, if I change the prop name back to `value` (instead of `bar`), then the value of `custom-input` will update each and every time I udpate the value of `message`.

[again, here is the video description of what I am talking about:   https://www.loom.com/share/6a23d0791c2444068e964b388ed5497e]

Why is that?  Why should it matter what name I give the prop?  Does it have to be named `value` because I am binding to the `value` attribute?  If so, why?

In short, what is going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the attribute must be named `value` because you are using `v-model` to bind. `v-model` is an abbrevistion of binding the attribute `value` and listening to the event `input`. It's a special use case for binding a value two ways.

So, this is exactly the same:

```
<custom-input v-model="user" />
```

And:

```
<custom-input :value="user" @input="user = $event" />
```

If you prefer the full attribute notation:

```
<custom-input v-bind:value="user" v-on:input="user = $event" />
```

With the variable `$event`, you can, directly in the template, access the emitted value. You can also write a function name without brackets into the template to pass the emitted value as first parameter (e.g. `@input="setUser"`, then declare a method `setUser(user)`).

Comment: I understand that the `attribute` has to be named `value`.  What I don't understand is why the `prop` has to be named `value`.  Why can't I name the `prop` something else?  In other words, why does this work:  `:value="value"`, but this does not work `:value="bar"`?

Comment: If you name the property `bar` in the child, and in the parent you are using `v-model`, you are actually binding the value from the parent to the property `value` which is then not defined in the child and not watched. You only have a one way binding via events to the parent. In that case you need to use `v-bind:bar="..."` and `v-on:input="..."` instead of `v-model` in the parent to make it work again.

Comment: Great - I now feel like I'm 75% of the way there.  I get what you are saying.  But I am now wondering, why then will `custom-input` update once when I set `bar` as the prop in the child and use `v-model` in the parent?  In other words, it is two-way-binding -- but just for one update.  After that it is one-way binding?  Why?

Comment: You are probably changing the `bar` value in the child component and then update the parent with that value (by emitting the `input` event). If you change the value in the parent, the child won't get updated (when using `:bar` and `v-model`). Use the [Vue DevTools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) for the Chrome DevTools to see what component currently holds which value.  Keep also in mind that it discouraged to directly modify a value of a parent (except it is a primitive value or a String).

Answer (score 0):

```
props is used to get data down from a parent component to a child component
$emit is used to send back data from the child to the parent
v-model is used for 2 way data binding
always make the data reactive with a return data(){return{...}}
props example:
Vue.component('product',{
  template:`
      <div>
         <item :items="items"/>
      </div>
`,
    data() {
      return{
        items:'hi'
      }
  }
})

Vue.component('item',{
  template:`
<div>
    {{items}}
</div>
`,
  props:{
    items:{
      type:String,
      required:false
    }
  }
})

var app= new Vue({
  el:"#app"
})

//in html file
<div id="app">
<product/>
</div>
```